# Xcode / Swift | Button animation resets automatically when clicking the UITextField

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

Basically I created a button in the MainStoryboard on a Controller named "button_login" and connected it to the ViewController.swift. Now I want the button in the next Controller that I also connected to a loginViewController to move up with an animation, so I wrote the animation in the viewDidAppear function. Now I also added textFields to let the user type in something like his username and password. The problem is, when I type in something in the UITextField, the button directly moves back to its old position where it came from before the animation.
How do I solve this problem? I really don't know why this happens...
To let you know about the code I added the two important parts of the loginViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label_title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label_subtitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView_username: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var textField_username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView_password: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var textField_password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var button_login: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var label_alreadyHaveAccount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var button_register: UIButton!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.button_login.frame.origin.y += 32.5
        self.label_title.alpha = 1
        self.label_subtitle.alpha = 1
    }, completion: { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            self.imageView_username.alpha = 1
            self.textField_username.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                self.imageView_password.alpha = 1
                self.textField_password.alpha = 1
            }, completion: { _ in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                    self.label_alreadyHaveAccount.alpha = 1
                    self.button_register.alpha = 1
                })
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: If you are using NSLayoutConstraints in your storyboard you should consider changing these constraints instead of using the button's frame

Comment: @Teetz What exactly do you mean? Can you give an example? Basically I constraint the button at the beginning with vertical spacing to the textFields and I also thought that maybe this is the problem, that it recognizes this constraint and the moves it back as I constrained it, but even deleting these constraints doesnt help...

Comment: You could either change your constraint constant (or add a new one and deactivate the old one) or you could use the transform property for animations (this is what i recommend). Show us your constraints and stuff in order to help you ;)